# Send email having an object as body with win32com

Tags: python, pywin32, win32com, prettytable

I am trying to send an email using win32com and have an object as body, such as:

```
outlook = win32com.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = 'receiver@email.com'
mail.Subject = 'subject of email'
mail.HtmlBody = table
mail.send
```

Where:

```
table = PrettyTable(['Header1', 'Header2'])
table.add_row(['row1col1', 'row1col2'])
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: Objects for SAFEARRAYS must be sequences (of sequences), or a buffer object.
```

I have tried to get the string out of the `table object` as `table.get_string()` as well as  `str(table)`. In both cases, the entire `table object` is printed as a `string` on a single line (it loses the `table` format)

EDIT:

I can send the `table` via email if I send `table.get_html_string()` as email body, however, I'm losing all the borders, which is ok..ish, but not great ...

SECOND EDIT:

`PrettyTable` provides an API to print tables in Python and eventually, it returns an object.

Basically, I am trying to get that object (which when I call `print table` I get back a well formatted table) and dump it into an email

Comment: You might want to mention what `PrettyTable` is as well. I'm not familiar with that object

Comment: I have added a SECOND EDIT to my question